# Replace Wordpress text with custom text

Tags: wordpress, text, replace

I created a Wordpress site and I want to replace every occurrence of the word Wordpress example:

```
Wordpress => MySite
```

Is there any plugin to do what I want or any function that should I create?Or should I replace all the words manually?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a support request for a third-party software, here namely Wordpress. It is much better suited on a venue focussing on Wordpress support like the Wordpress Support Forums or - if in the scope of that site - on Wordpress Stackexchange.

Comment: [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3675/12615) will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [Wordpress Search and Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) that will do what you need.
If you download a PHP script from the link, place it in the root of your site and then navigate to it will find and replace any term in the site database and / or files.

Obviously make sure you remove after you're done and it's better to rename it something less obvious before you upload it.